# Why NSDate from string has one day less?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

if I try:

```
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"];
```

and

```
[formatter dateFromString:@"20120423"];
```

My new NSDate object will be: 2012 04 **22**. Why one day less?

Thank

Comment: what is zone set in your simulator or device. It will default to that zone.

Comment: it is about the timezone... the difference can be only a few hours only ()or even just one, like `2017-06-02 00:00:00 GMT+1` is equal to `2017-06-01 23:00:00 GMT+0` which seems like it is one day short, if you care about the years-months-days values.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have problems with time zone and it can be solved by adding this line of code:

```
formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"];
```

Comment: Really helpful buddy !!! I was solving issue from last one day and this simple liner worked :)

Answer (score 7):

For those who looks for **swift 3** version

```
let formatter        = DateFormatter()
formatter.timezone   = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd"
formatter.date(from: "20120423")
```

Answer (score 0):

For one liners using **Swift 3**

```
Date.init(dateString: "2014-07-31", format: "yyyy-MM-dd", timeZone: TimeZone.init(abbreviation: "GMT")!)
```